# How to run Python script (for testing) with Docker?

Tags: python, docker

Context:
I created a Flask application that makes a JSON object available on localhost/api. I am also using nginx and gunicorn to help build my server. This whole application is containerized using Docker.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10
ENV CONTAINER_HOME=/var/www
ADD . $CONTAINER_HOME
WORKDIR $CONTAINER_HOME
RUN pwd 
RUN pip3 install -r $CONTAINER_HOME/requirements.txt
# RUN python3 $CONTAINER_HOME/src/tests/tests.py ???? Should I add this line?
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - flask
  flask:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: flask
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 "src.api.app:app"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - project

networks:
  my-network:
```

Requirements:
Now I want to test my API. I have written a Python script (see tests.py in Dockerfile) which runs fine in my local environment and performs the tests.

Problem:

1. I want to automate the API testing in the Docker container and not manually do it on my host terminal.
2. Once the container starts running and my JSON object is available, only then I want to run the test.py file, which has the tests that I want to do on my JSON object on localhost/api.

How do I solve this problem? How do I automate the test with Docker? Perhaps in Dockerfile or in docker-compose. Or should I create a different sub-directory in my project directory and create a separate Dockerfile to run test.py?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a project structure like this:

```
├── app.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── nginx-config
│   └── nginx.conf
├── requirements.txt
└── test.py
```

`docker-compose.yml` (Add a `test` service which uses the same image as built for the `flask` service.)

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - flask

  flask:
    container_name: flask
    image: flask:latest
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: flask
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 "app:app"

  test:
    image: flask:latest
    container_name: test
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    command: python3 test.py
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10

ARG CONTAINER_HOME=/var/www

ADD . $CONTAINER_HOME
WORKDIR $CONTAINER_HOME

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt`

```
Flask==3.0.2
gunicorn==21.2.0
requests==2.31.0
```

A minimal application and tests:

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`test.py`

```
import requests

def test_api():
    url = "http://nginx:80/"

    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200, "API did not return 200 OK!"
    assert response.text == "Hello, World!", "API response did not match!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_api()
    print("Test passed!")
```

Now when you fire up the stack the `test` service will be triggered last and will test the API via NGINX.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! Accepted your answer 